# Loading a table from a separate HTML

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

Say I have two files:

```
index.html
table.html
```

where `table.html` holds my table (e.g the following contents):

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe" id="my_table">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>school</th>
      <th>county</th>
      <th>zipcode</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>XX</td>
      <td>YY</td>
      <td>ZZ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>XX</td>
      <td>YY</td>
      <td>ZZ</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and `index.html` just has the [`datatables`](https://www.datatables.net/) code, e.g.

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    $("#my_table").dataTable();
  })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above doesn't work, because the reference `my_table` is not found by `index.html`. How can I have it "embed" (or make it "aware of") `table.html`?

Comment: You could load your html page with the table in an iFrame. That's one way. But unless your #my_table tag exists within the current document, your current code will not find the tag.

Comment: Thanks @mwilson I guess I don't know how to exactly do that yet. Sorry, learning some of the basics of this still :)

Answer (score 1):

Use an iframe to render the tablepage within your main page:

**Main HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="tablepage.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Table Page HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" class="dataframe" id="my_table">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>school</th>
      <th>county</th>
      <th>zipcode</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>XX</td>
      <td>YY</td>
      <td>ZZ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>XX</td>
      <td>YY</td>
      <td>ZZ</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="theJS.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#my_table').DataTable();

});
```

Comment: This prevents datatables from working. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert HTML page with `load()` function

```
 <script>
$(function(){
    $("#table").load("table.html"); 
});
 </script>
```

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">  
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      $(function(){
          $("#table").load("table.html"); 
      });
      $(function(){
          $("#my_table").dataTable();
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="table"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And table.html

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe" id="my_table">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>school</th>
      <th>county</th>
      <th>zipcode</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>XX</td>
      <td>YY</td>
      <td>ZZ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>XX</td>
      <td>YY</td>
      <td>ZZ</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hmm, this is preventing datatables from working. Not sure why.

Comment: I have reported the problem [here](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/655).

Comment: may be use `setTimeout(function()` to delay the either function `load();` or datatable `dataTable();` with approach in answer, everything loading when open page `index.html` so putting delay can be a solution here

Answer (score 0):

You can user [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) (see last example) to get the second file from server and then append the HTML code in your current page and then you'll be able to modify it.